# Getting Class 'app\models\User' not found in Yii2 view even though imported with use

Tags: php, yii, namespaces, yii2

I am getting the error:

> PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'app\models\User' not found'

My relevant structure is as below:

```
admin/ <--- namespace admin\
    system/
        controllers/
            MembersController.php
        models/
        themes/
            default/
                members/
                     partials/
                        edit-something.php
common/ <--- namespace common\
    vendor/
    widgets/
        views/
            widget-view.php
        MyWidget.php
system/ <--- namespace app\
    controllers/
    models/
        User.php
```

Now to cause this Exception I am accessing a controller method using `namespace admin\controllers;` which then renders a view called `edit-something.php` from `admin/system/themes/default/members/partials/edit-something.php`;

**Action method:**

The action method is a little complicated, in that it calls a common function to run an `AJAX` request and then runs a callback function that does the grunt work, that summarized as:

```
$response['output'] = $this->renderPartial('partials/edit-something');
return $response;
```

The `$response` is then returned as the response from the callback and is eventually output on the page as `JSON` as the response to the `AJAX` request.

Inside the aforementioned view file we are making a call to `MyWidget::widget(...)`.

Inside the widget I am importing the `User` model with `use app\models\User;` and there seems to be no issues.

Further down in the widget we are rendering the view file located at: `common/widgets/views/avatar.php` and inside this view file I am also importing the `User` model with `use app\models\User;` and then calling a function from it with `User::MyFunction()`, as below:

**common/widgets/views/avatar.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\models\User;

?>

<span class="initial"><?=Html::encode(User::getUserInitial($username))?></span>
```

The above line where it is being called is the one that appears to be causing the problem.

**system/models/User.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use common\helpers\GeneralHelper as General;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;

class User extends Model implements IdentityInterface {

    //..........

    public static function getUserInitial($username) {
        return strtoupper(General::getFirstAlphaNum($username));
    }

}
```

Now, my IDE finds this class and function fine; but for some reason that appears to be where the error is coming from.

Is there some kind of namespace issue here - what am I doing wrong where Yii cannot seem to find the class/function whereas my IDE seems to have no issue with it?

Comment: please show the controller /action code .. too (with namespace and use)

Comment: and show  where is missing file in your structure

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated with more info on the controller method.

Comment: @bxN5 Not sure what you mean? It can't find the `app\models\User` class.

Comment: check your config
I had the similar problem and find a definition of non-exist class in my config

Comment: @bxN5 Yeah, already been through my config.

Comment: @Brett   . i need  see the use declaration in you controller  and the User model call  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge all of them? What do you mean you need to see the the User model call - do you mean the code where I am calling the User model where it is reporting the error?

Comment: exactly ... is important for undestand  if you are declaring the use in the right place

Comment: @scaisEdge Well I'm not even calling the `User` model in the controller as it's not used there, that's why I didn't include that data in my question - just a bunch of other unrelated classes.

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated once again with more details on where I am calling the `User` models function and where it is causing the problem. If you want to see my `use` statements in the controller let me know, but as I said they aren't really relevant.

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont' understand  where  you have placed the class named User .. please show me the exact path where you have this class ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Sorry, I thought I included it in the structure. I have now added it and you will see it right at the bottom.

Comment: could you update  your post and add  the User Class declaration file that you have in system\models\User ?

Comment: @scaisEdge Updated. Come to think of it though I probably should move that function et al into a common model.

Comment: @scaisEdge Ok, moved the static functions to a common model like they should have been in the first place and all is good now. :)

Comment: well  .. I'm glad you finally found a solution .. good job

Comment: @Brett I am facing the same issue but I want to use `app\models\User`.